# Boost Sparse Matrix Memory Requirement

Tags: c++, boost, sparse-matrix

I'm thinking of using Boost's Sparse Matrix for a computation where minimal memory usage is the goal. Unfortunately, the [documentation page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/matrix_sparse.htm) didn't include a discussion of the sparse matrix implementation's memory usage when I looked through it. Nor am I sure how to determine how much memory the sparse matrix is using at any given time.

How much memory will the sparse matrix use? Can you quote a source?

How can I find out how much memory the matrix is using at a given time `t`?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot give you an exact answer. But generally speaking a sparse matrix uses an amount of memory that is a multiple of the number of nonzero entries of the matrix. A common format stores all nonzero entries in an array 'A' (row by row). Stores than a second array 'B' which gives the column-index of the corresponding nonzero entry from 'A' and a third array telling me where in array 'A' row x begins.
Assuming datatypes type_nnz, type_index a N*N sparse matrix with nnz nonzero elements the memory requirement is

```
sizeof(type_nnz)*nnz + sizeof(type_index)*(nnz+N)
```